# mysql conditional query - complicated

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, distinct

I want to get distinct values for a field, let say: field1...
This needs a query like: "select distinct(field1) from table"

However for some records, field1 is empty and there is another column that is an alternative to field1, which is field2. For the records where field1 is empty I need to use the value of field2. I think I need sort of a conditional select statement with if control something like:

```
 select distinct( (if(field1!='') field1 else field2) ) from table
```

I have no idea on how to write it. Any help is appreciated...

Comment: maybe not such complicated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
 IF( coalesce(field1,'') <> '', field1, field2)
)
FROM table
```

This would work for both null and empty `field1`.

Answer (score 2):

SELECT DISTINCT IFNULL(field1,field2) FROM table

should do the trick.

Comment: your solution returned 64 results while my query below returned 74!?! i m analyzing the results to see the differences and will post my comments later here.

Answer (score 0):

i think i did it (not sure if the result is correct):

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
 IF( field1 <> '', field1, field2)
)
FROM table
```

Comment: The NULL value and the empty string are not the same. Maybe that explains the difference?